# Any prediction method for this?

Tags: r, prediction

This is my dataset.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjsR2.jpg)

I was trying to create a prediction for Global_Sales and Types (doesn't matter they at x or y). I tried several model, they all come out error and cannot be run.

This is the analysis I did. By using this code.

```
ggplot(vgsa, aes(x = Types, y = Global_Sales)) +
  geom_line(color = 'blue', size = 5) + 
  labs(y = "Global_Sales", title = "Global_Sales of Video Games")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJRIF.jpg)

Any suggest prediction model?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  In particular, post your input data using `dput()` or `dput(head())`.

Comment: thanks, I try it 1st.